# Showing 2 ImageViews in Android layout with weight

Tags: android, layout, android-framelayout

While doing this I get the images but less room than I need underneath and above.  The logos should be right to the top.  Here is the xml

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:shrinkColumns="*"  android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ffffff">
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView00"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:src="@drawable/customlogo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0px"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" android:paddingRight="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:src="@drawable/customlogo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0px"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" android:paddingRight="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView00" android:text="Driver"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:tag="0"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0px"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#ffffff" android:tag="1" android:text="Bus"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0px"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:text="Tim"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:tag="0"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0px"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#ffffff" android:tag="1" android:text="6"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0px"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
</TableRow>
```

The screen looks like

[two muppets http://208.107.82.38/pics/screenshot.png](http://208.107.82.38/pics/screenshot.png)
I want the logos to not have padding on top or bottom.  Is there a better way to do layout.  Thank yuo

Answer (score 0):

You should change `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the ImageViews.

Answer (score 0):

try this

appImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id."your imageview id ");

appImage.getLayoutParams().height = 500;
appImage.getLayoutParams().width = 700;